java Spring - join custom con CriteriaBuilder y @manytoone con columnas que no son id
Tengo las siguientes entidades
public class MovimientoBienes {

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "CODCEN", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO_CENTRO", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
 private VistaBienes vistaBienes;

 @EmbeddedId
 private MovimientoBienesId movimientoBienesId;
 .....
}

A continuación la clase Id
public class MovimientoBienesId {


 @Column(name = "CODCEN")
 private Integer codCentro;

 @Column(name = "CDARTI")
 private Integer codArticulo;

 @Column(name = "FECMVB")
 private Integer fechaMovimiento;

 @Column(name = "SECMOV")
 private Integer secuenciaMovimiento;

}

La siguiente entidad es así
public class VistaBienes {
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "vistaBienes")
 private List<MovimientoBienes> movimientosBienes;

 @EmbeddedId
 private VistaBienesId vistaBienesId;

 @Column(name = "CODIGO")
 private Integer codigo;
..........
}

Y su clase id:
public class VistaBienesId extends ValueObject {


 @Column(name = "CODIGO_DPTO")
 private Integer codigoDpto;

 @Column(name = "CODIGO_CENTRO")
 private Integer codigoCentro;

}

Por ultimo donde se esta montando el criteriaBuilder
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<HistoricoMovimientosDto> query = cb.createQuery(HistoricoMovimientosDto.class);
    Root<MovimientoBienes> root = query.from(MovimientoBienes.class);

    // Añadir joins necesarios
    Join<MovimientoBienes, VistaBienes> vistaJoin = root.join("vistaBienes", JoinType.INNER);

Así como esta el error que me da es
referencedColumnNames(CODIGO_CENTRO, CODIGO) of es.backend.personal.domain.model.MovimientoBienes.vistaBien referencing es.backend.personal.domain.model.VistaBienes not mapped to a single property

¿como puedo hacer un join de ambas tablas usando las columnas codigo_centro y codigo, siendo que en la clase VistaBienes tiene mas columnas primarias (que no quiero usar) y la columna  codigo no es primaria.
